# What is blueman-manager process doing more than bluedevil does already?

Tags: kde, bluetooth, plasma, bluez, blueman

I have this odd problem in Plasma/Kubuntu on a Macbook: [bluetooth audio being lost after media pause](https://askubuntu.com/q/1425258/925128) - with two UE Boom speakers (2 and 3). The Plasma BT tool is `bluedevil`, as said [here](https://discuss.kde.org/t/what-is-the-plasma-bluetooth-tool/7628/2?u=cipricus) on Discuss.

I have fixed it by installing `blueman` and ***keeping `blueman-manager` running***, although, theoretically, as said at the Discuss link, Bluedevil is just a UI for `bluez`, like `blueman`. Be that as it may, `blueman-manager`, on the other hand, seems to bring something more than what `bluez` does under Bluedevil.

Bluedevil is not a process. While running, the Plasma BT tool seems to involve two processes in System Activity: `bluetoothd` and `obexd`. `blueman` is not a process either. Installing the package adds a program called "Bluetooth Manager" which runs `blueman-manager` and starts three processes: `blueman-manager`, `blueman-applet` and `blueman-tray` (`blueman-mechani` too, but for a short time).

I have noticed that for my BT speaker not to lose sound after pause `blueman-manager` has to be running at the moment of un-pause action.

The odd thing is that the `blueman-manager` process is closed if the `blueman` tray icon is clicked.

So, now I have fixed my problem by auto-starting `blueman-manager` and avoiding closing it, as seen in my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1493695/925128) under askubuntu linked question.

But I am curious what exactly is `blueman-manager` doing more than what is already happening in Plasma bluetooth-wise, Kubuntu 23.10?